# Find out $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI' to access data

Tags: php, json

I have the following code(`test.php`):

```
   if(!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/test/test') !== false)
    {
        if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
            date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

        $dashboard_type = 'overview';
        $dashboard_sdate = date('Ymd', strtotime('-29 day'));

        if(!empty($_GET['type']))
            $dashboard_type = $_GET['type'];

        if(!empty($_GET['sdate']))
            $dashboard_sdate = $_GET['sdate'];

        if(!empty($_GET['key']))
        {

            test_process_request($_GET['key'], $dashboard_type, $dashboard_sdate);
            exit;
        }
    }

    function test_process_request($key_in, $type_in, $sdate_in)
    {
        //pack data

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

My problem is that I do not know how the request uri should look like to request data from this function?

I know that it must be like `test.com/test/test.php?key=FILLINAKEY`. However, how to actually fill in more parameteres to access and display the requested data in my browser?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Comment: @Deadooshka Yes I have read this, however, still do not know which structure my URL could have. I appreciate your reply!

Comment: can you explain more what do you need? i tried to read your question several times, still don't know what is your aim.

Comment: @Yazan Thx for your answer! What I am aming for is, to build a link to display the data in my browser(the json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok now i got what you mean,

i think you have 3 types of URI

1- Query String which is well known:

```
http://www.example.com/page.php?p=2&p2=yes...
```

2- cleamn URLs pattern, which takes params as values beterrn / / , like if they are folders,

```
http://www.example.com/page/2/yes/...
```

more about this [here](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74170-clean-urls-with-php/)

3- data structured params, where you pass 1 param with JSON or XML content that contains all params or action names you need

```
http://www.example.com/page.php?data={JSON-STRING}
```

and now its up to you, to decide which approach you will take,
some of this need extra configuration maybe, or using .htaccess 
and others can be just coded.

hope this helps you